# Oracle 12c Index unusable after partition drop

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, database-partitioning

In Oracle 11g if global index maintained during execution of the DROP partition command then command could take hours to complete. Oracle 12c said DROP partition command executes immediately and index will remain usable.

I had database table in Oracle 11g which use partition drop for purging. But never able to utilize partition drop due to above 11g index unusable issue. So I updated the database to Oracle 12c. But still when I drop the partition index become unusable. I disabled the Oracle database backward compatibility but still issue is there. Interestingly when I created a new table in 12c it works as expected. But not for tables upgraded from 11g to 12c.

Did anybody expedience similar issue ?

Comment: pls check the limitation of this feature [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-087B87A6-959A-40C6-82AF-36E401FD089B.htm#VLDBG14107)

Comment: My table has primary key, foreign keys, partitions, indexes and a trigger.  I don't think any of limiting factors are there.

Comment: The limitation are listet in the document referenced above. Basically no SYS, domain index, heap table and object types. In your situation with migrated table I'd open an SR with Oracle..

Comment: I added a ticket to Oracle. I'll update if I receive anything useful from them.

Comment: Oracle has accepted this as a bug